# Solving 'impossible' integrals with a new (?) trick

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, integration, trigonometric-functions

The following identities have been suggested based on formulas in a [previous question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4844145/trigonometric-formula-for-solving-quadratic-equations).

If complex $\theta_1=\cos^{-1}(p)$ and $\theta_2=\sec^{-1}(p)$, where $p\in(-1, 0) \cup (1, \infty)$, then the following relation holds:

> $$e^{i\theta_1}=\frac{1-\tan\frac{\theta_2}{2} }{1+\tan\frac{\theta_2}{2}}. 
>  \tag{1}\label{463459_1}$$

And for $p\in(-\infty, -1)\cup (0, 1)$, we have

> $$e^{-i\theta_1}=\frac{1-\tan\frac{\theta_2}{2} }{1+\tan\frac{\theta_2}{2}}. \tag{2}\label{463459_2}$$

If complex $\theta_1=\sin^{-1}(p)$ and $\theta_2=\csc^{-1}(p)$, where $p\in(-\infty, -1)\cup (0, 1)$, then the following relation holds:

> $$ie^{i\theta_1}=-\tan\frac{\theta_2}{2}.\tag{3}\label{463459_3}$$

And for $p\in(-1, 0) \cup (1, \infty)$ we have

> $$ie^{-i\theta_1}=\tan\frac{\theta_2}{2}.\tag{4}\label{463459_4}$$

There are several variants that we can obtain by equating (and simplifying) the trigonometric formulas for quadratic equations from [my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4844145/trigonometric-formula-for-solving-quadratic-equations).

I have noticed that for certain trigonometric integrals defined over permissible intervals of $p$, the evaluation simplifies considerably. For instance, consider the following definite integral:

> $$\int_2^5 \sqrt{\tan\left(\frac{\csc^{-1}(x)}{2}\right)} \,dx.\tag{5}\label{463459_5}$$

[This integral calculator](https://www.integral-calculator.com/#expr=sqrttan%28arccscx%2F2%29&lbound=2&ubound=5) returns the following:

> No antiderivative could be found within the given time limit, or all
> supported integration methods were tried unsuccessfully. Note that
> many functions don't have an elementary antiderivative.

But it gives an approximation of $1.178881841955109.$

Given that the interval $[2, 5]$ is within the permissible values of $p$, I can use $e^{i\cos^{-1}(p)}=\tan\frac{\csc^{-1}(p)}{2}$ (derived from identities \eqref{463459_1} and \eqref{463459_4}), valid for $p\in[-1, 0) \cup [1, \infty)$, to convert \eqref{463459_5} into

> $$\int_2^5 \sqrt{e^{i\cos^{-1}(x)}}\,dx.\tag{6}\label{463459_6}$$

[The same calculator](https://www.integral-calculator.com/#expr=%28e%5E%28iarccosx%29%29%5E%281%2F2%29&lbound=2&ubound=5) provides the same answer but now displaying the steps as well. As a second example, *Mathematica*  is unable to solve this integral (as confirmed in the comments):

$$\int_{2}^{3}  \frac{{1 - \tan\frac{{\sec^{-1}x}}{2}}}{{1 + \tan\frac{{\sec^{-1}x}}{2}}}\sqrt{\tan\frac{\csc^{-1}x}{2}}\,dx\tag{7}$$

Neither [this integral calculator](https://www.integral-calculator.com/#expr=%28%281-tan%28%28arcsecx%29%2F2%29%29%2F%20%281%2Btan%28%28arcsecx%29%2F2%29%29%20%29%2Asqrt%28tan%28%28arccscx%29%2F2%29%29&lbound=2&ubound=3). Although both the calculator and [Wolfram Alpha can give you a numerical approximation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate%20%28%281-tan%28%28arcsecx%29%2F2%29%29%2F%20%281%2Btan%28%28arcsecx%29%2F2%29%29%20%29*sqrt%28tan%28%28arccscx%29%2F2%29%29%20from%202%20to%203&lang=es). However, thanks to this new trick, you can convert $(7)$ into

$$\int_{2}^{3} e^{\frac{3i\arccos(x)}{2}}\,dx\tag{8}$$

Note that [this integral calculator](https://www.integral-calculator.com/#expr=e%5E%28i%2Aarccosx%29%2Ae%5E%280.5%2Ai%2Aarccosx%29&lbound=2&ubound=3) has no problem solving (elegantly!) integral $(8)$.

Other examples of integrals that at least Wolfram Alpha is not capable of solving but that can be evaluated using the transformations described in this blog (each integral is linked to its solution in the integral calculator):

[$$\int_{2}^{3} \ln(x) \sqrt{\tan\left(\frac12\csc^{-1}x\right)} \, dx\tag{9}$$](https://www.integral-calculator.com/#expr=lnxsqrt%28e%5E%28i%2Aarccosx%29&lbound=2&ubound=3)

[$$\int_{2}^{3} \sin\left(\tan\frac12\csc^{-1}{x}\right) \, dx\tag{10}$$](https://www.integral-calculator.com/#expr=sin%28e%5E%28i%2Aarccosx%29%29&lbound=2&ubound=3)

So far I have considered integrals involving $\tan{\left(\frac12\csc^{-1}x\right)}$. However, this technique can be applied to a countless number of cases that surpass my initial expectations (especially if you consider that sine and cosine functions can be expressed in terms of tangents of half angles.). For example, consider the integral [$\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{20}}\sqrt{\tan{x}}\,dx$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate%20sqrt%28tanx%29%20from%20pi%2F4%20to%20pi%2F20&lang=es). This can be solved by letting $x=\frac12\csc^{-1}t$, where $\,dx=-\frac{1}{2t\sqrt{t^2-1}}\,dt$, transforming the original integral into [$-\frac12\int_{\csc(\frac{\pi}{2})}^{\csc(\frac{\pi}{10})}e^{\frac12i\arccos(t)} \left(\frac{1}{t\sqrt{t^2-1}}\right) \, dt$](https://www.integral-calculator.com/#expr=-0.5%2Asqrt%28e%5E%28i%2Aarccost%29%29%2A%281%2F%28tsqrt%28t%5E2-1%29&intvar=t&lbound=csc%28pi%2F2%29&ubound=csc%28pi%2F10%29). Certainly, there will be instances where employing these transformations might seem overly intricate, akin to cutting bread with a saw. However, what I aim to emphasize is the remarkable versatility of this technique.

**Was this trick known in the world of integrals?**

**EDITED**. Not exactly the same technique , but I think this is somehow related to my question.  According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_using_Euler%27s_formula), using Euler's formula, any trigonometric function may be written in terms of complex exponential functions, namely  $e^{ix}$ and $e^{-ix}$ and then integrated. This technique is often simpler and faster than using trigonometric identities or integration by parts, and is sufficiently powerful to integrate any rational expression involving trigonometric functions.

Crossposted at [MathSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4856129/evaluating-int-25-sqrt-tan-left-frac-csc-1x2-right-dx-us).

This story will continue on my [blog](https://geometriadominicana.blogspot.com/2024/03/integration-using-some-euler-like.html).

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Integrate%5BSqrt%5BTan%5BArcCsc%5Bx%5D%2F2%5D%5D%2C+%7Bx%2C+2%2C+5%7D%5D) evaluates your definite integral (5) and also gives the indefinite integral in closed form .... $$\int\sqrt{\tan{\left(\frac{\csc^{-1}(x)}{2}\right)}}\,dx=\frac{2}{3} \left(\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x^2}}+2\right) x \sqrt{x-\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x^2}} x}$$

Comment: @CarloBeenakker: WA may be using $\tan\frac{\csc^{-1}(x)}{2}=x-\sqrt{x^2-1}$ as Quanto mentioned on MathSE. However, I don't see it being simpler to rewrite in terms of radicals. For instance, the calculator linked rewrites integral $(7)$ in terms of radicals, but the solution it provides is very tedious due to all those radicals, especially when compared to the resolution of $(8)$ which simplifies immediately.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker: Replace the square root with a cubic root, and WA no longer provides a closed form (unless, perhaps, you activate the PRO version). Meanwhile, using the formulas I suggest, the linked calculator has no issues in providing even the steps of the solution.

Comment: just for the record, in response to the question what would happen if I replace the square root by a cubic root: Mathematica can evaluate this for any power $p$ of the tangent, $$\int \tan^p\left(\frac{\operatorname{csc}^{-1}(x)}{2}\right)\,dx=-\frac{2^p x \left(p \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x^2}}+1\right) \left(x \sin ^2\left(\frac{1}{2} \csc ^{-1}(x)\right)\right)^p}{p^2-1}$$ none of this is particularly instructive, but it just indicates that these integrals are not that hard.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker: Okay, but I was referring to the free version of WA, and the integrals I present here are not the most difficult ones I can think of. My main point is not exactly that current software cannot solve these integrals, but that the identities I present significantly simplify manual work.

Comment: MathJax note: If you go to the trouble of `\tag`ging your equations, then you might as well `\label` them and use `\eqref` later.  This way one gets clickable links, so that a commenter or an answerer, as well as your post itself, can refer, for example, to your \eqref{463459_1}.  I edited accordingly.

Comment: $(6)$ is not the same here and on MSE

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Please, read the comments on MathSE.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker: Can Mathematica compute this one? $$\int_{2}^{3}  \frac{{1 - \tan\frac{{\sec^{-1}x}}{2}}}{{1 + \tan\frac{{\sec^{-1}x}}{2}}} \sqrt{\tan\frac{\csc^{-1}x}{2}} \,dx$$

Comment: no it cannot (it returns a symbolic answer, but it is very long and Mathematica is unable to simplify it into a compact expression)

Comment: I see. Thank you. This is the expression I obtain using the transformations presented in my original question:
$$\frac{1}{5} e^{\frac{5}{2}i\arccos(x)} - e^{\frac{1}{2}i\arccos(x)}$$

Comment: It is considered good practice to wait a while (at least a week, say; not just a couple of days) before crossposting a question from math.SE here to avoid duplicate work

Answer (score 12):

Not a full answer, but too long for a comment.

The OP's relations are related to the Gudermannian, see, e.g., https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Gudermannian.html, as
$$
\operatorname{gd}(i \theta_1) = \theta_2
$$
for $\theta_k$ in \eqref{463459_2}, the other cases have similar identities.
The Gudermannian itself is related to the limit $m\to1$ (or $k\to1$) of the parameter $m$/modulus $k$ of Jacobi elliptic functions, and is therefore sometimes called "hyperbolic amplitude", see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gudermannian_function.
Elliptic functions are known to fulfill a large number of identities, especially when combined with Jacobi’s Imaginary Transformation (https://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobisImaginaryTransformation.html) of the complex plane.
These identities give rise to many identities for the Gudermannian.

Comment: `\mathrm{gd}` and `\operatorname{gd}` yield different results in some commonplace contexts. For example $3\operatorname{gd}(i\theta_1)$ does not look the same as $3\mathrm{gd}(i\theta_1)$ and the latter is considered incorrect by everyone who has any orthographic standards in such things. And in $\operatorname{gd}x$ you see more space to the right of $\operatorname{gd}$ than you do in $\operatorname{gd}(x),$ and that doesn't work with `\mathrm{gd}`.

Comment: +1 It is true that the gudermannian was known to math students up to 100 years ago or so.  As the inverse of the Mercator projection it dates to over 500 years ago.  Nowadays it is commonly known only for certain special computations.  But it's not a "new trick".

Comment: @GeraldEdgar: In Fred's response, there is no application to the simplification of integrals in the sense that I have described in my question. I suppose that's why he says his response doesn't fully answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

*For the pleasure of working an interesting integral.*
$$I=\int\sqrt{\tan{\left(\frac{\csc^{-1}(x)}{2}\right)}}\,dx$$
$$x=\csc (2 t)\quad \implies \quad dx=-2 \cot (2 t) \csc (2 t)\,dt$$
$$I=-2 \int \cot (2 t) \csc (2 t) \sqrt{\tan (t)}\,dt$$
$$t=\tan ^{-1}\left(u^2\right)\quad \implies \quad dt=\frac{2 u}{u^4+1}\,du$$
$$I=\int \frac{u^4-1}{u^2}\,du=\frac{u^4+3}{3u}+C$$

Back to $x=\csc \left(2 \tan ^{-1}\left(u^2\right)\right)$

$$I=\frac{2}{3}  \left(\sqrt{x^2-1}+2 x\right)\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x^2-1}}+C$$
For the definite integral
$$\int_2^5\sqrt{\tan{\left(\frac{\csc^{-1}(x)}{2}\right)}}\,dx=4 \sqrt{3}-\sqrt{6}-\frac{7}{3} \sqrt{2}=1.17888$$

For the second integral
$$J=\int\sqrt{e^{-i\sin^{-1}(x)}}\,dx$$ Mathematica returns a quite complicated result (have a look [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Integrate%5BSqrt%5BE%5E%28-I*ArcSin%5Bx%5D%29%5D%2Cx%5D)). If the link is broken, just copy/paste in Wolfram Alpha

`Integrate[Sqrt[E^(-I*ArcSin[x])],x]`

You will need a lot of simplifications to obtain the result.

**Edit**

If, as @Carlo Beenakker did, we generalize the problem to
$$I_p=\int \Bigg[\tan \left(\frac{1}{2} \csc ^{-1}(x)\right) \Bigg]^p\,dx$$

Using first $x=\csc (2 t)$ and then $t=\tan ^{-1}\left(u\right)$, we end with
$$I_p=\frac{1}{2}\int  \left(u^2-1\right) u^{p-2}\,du=\frac{1}{2} u^{p-1} \left(\frac{u^2}{p+1}+\frac{1}{1-p}\right)$$ where
$$u=\tan \left(\frac{1}{2} \csc ^{-1}(x)\right)$$ that is to say  (assuming $x>0$)
$$I_p=\frac{\left(x-\sqrt{x^2-1}\right)^p \left(x+p\, \sqrt{x^2-1}\right)}{1-p^2}$$

**Update**

In comments, the poster asked for
$$K=\int \frac{1-\tan \left(\frac{1}{2} \csc ^{-1}(x)\right)}{1+\tan \left(\frac{1}{2} \csc
   ^{-1}(x)\right)} \,\,\sqrt{\tan \left(\frac{1}{2} \csc ^{-1}(x)\right)} \,dx$$

Using the same sequence of changes of variables
$$K=-\int \frac{\left(u^2-1\right)^2}{u^2}\,du=-\frac{u^3}{3}+2 u+\frac{1}{u}+C$$ which, back to $t$ is
$$K=\frac{3+6 \tan (t)-\tan ^2(t)}{3 \sqrt{\tan (t)}}$$ Back to $x$
$$K=\frac{6 x \left(\sqrt{x^2-1}+x+1\right)+6 \sqrt{x^2-1}-4}{3
   \left(\sqrt{x^2-1}+x\right)^{3/2}}$$

Comment: Your integral $J$ is more complicated because you didn't even copy the integral $(6)$ correctly.

Comment: @EmmanuelJoséGarcía. You are correct. I shall fix it. I took it on MSE

Comment: You edited your answer, but still, your integral $J$ is not my integral $(6)$.

Comment: Can Mathematica evaluate the following integral? Both the integral calculator I linked in my question and Wolfram Alpha (using the free version) fail to evaluate it:
$$\int_{2}^{3} \left( \frac{{1 - \tan\frac{{\sec^{-1}x}}{2}}}{{1 + \tan\frac{{\sec^{-1}x}}{2}}} \right) \sqrt{\tan\frac{\csc^{-1}x}{2}} \,dx$$

Comment: @EmmanuelJoséGarcía. I shall add this one in my answer since it is nice.

Comment: OK. Did you notice your integral $J$ is **not** my integral $(6)$, right?

Comment: @EmmanuelJoséGarcía   For the definite integral the result is $\frac{4}{3}+\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{6}$

Comment: I think your answer $\frac{4}{3}+\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{6}$ is wrong. Please, check again.

Comment: @EmmanuelJoséGarcía. WA gives $0.298057$

Comment: Now I see that you wrote your integral $K$ incorrectly. In the first factor of the integrand, I use $\sec^{-1}x$, not $\csc^{-1}x$. The integral you solved is easier.

Comment: Using the identities I have presented here, that integral is a piece of cake. Here is the answer to the last, more complicated integral: $\frac{2}{5} (\sqrt{494 - 93\sqrt{3}} - 18)$.